# Computing limit of integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

We are supposed to calculate the limit of the integral $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin nx}{nx}dx$.

What I am currently thinking is this. Since $|\frac{\sin nx}{nx}|<\frac{1}{n}$, we can prove that this converges uniformly and can then use the dominated convergence theorem to shift the limit inside the integral, as in 
$\int_0^\pi \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{nx}dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{n} \,dx$.

However, I don't think that this is correct. Does someone know the correct way to solve this?

Comment: It is true that $\left| \dfrac{\sin(nx)} n \right| \le \dfrac 1 n$ but it is not true that $\left| \dfrac{\sin(nx)} {nx} \right| \le \dfrac 1 n,$ since $x$ may be near $0$ so that $1/x$ is large. In particular $\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{nx} \to 1$ as $x\to0. \qquad$

Comment: The first part of your comment says that the same thing is both true and not true, could you clarify?

Comment: Typo fixed. $\qquad$

Comment: 1) It's not true that $\left\lvert\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}\right \rvert<\frac1n$. 2) $\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}$ converges pointwise but not uniformly on $(0,\pi)$. 3) $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}\ne \frac1n$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : You win the sarcasm contest.

Comment: Don't know if you noticed, but the answer you accepted is simply _wrong_.

Comment: Is it really? How so? I honestly thought it was correct.

Comment: Because the way I wrote the English may be a little confusing that the limit function is $1$, but actually I didn't say that, I meant the dominated function can be taken as $1$, the limit function is $0$ (except for one point).

Answer (score 6):

By enforcing the substitution $x=\frac{z}{n}$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}\,dx = \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi n}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz.$$
In order to prove that **the wanted limit is zero** it is enough to show that $\int_{0}^{\pi n}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz$ is $o(n)$.
Since $|\sin(x)|<\min(1,x)$ we have
$$ \left|\int_{0}^{\pi n}\frac{\sin z}{z}\right|\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{z}{z}\,dz + \int_{1}^{\pi n}\frac{dz}{z} = 1+\log(\pi n) $$
and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

Use $|\sin u|\leq|u|$ to get $|\sin(nx)/nx|\leq 1$ for $x\in(0,\pi]$, then apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem because $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi}1 \, dx = \pi < \infty$.

Okay, sorry for my bad English, in fact, I was saying that the dominated function could be taken as the constant function $1$ on $[0,\pi]$. I was not saying that the limit function is $1$. And the limit function is $0$ (except for one point). So the integral is zero as well.

Comment: How to show that $\frac{\sin nx}{nx}$  is measurable

Comment: Continuous implies measurable.

Comment: It's continuous... so it should be measurable.

Comment: How is the function continuous on $[0,\pi]$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin nx}{nx}=1$ and and for $x\neq 0,\frac{\sin nx}{nx}\le \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: The point $x=0$ can be left out. So it is continuous on $(0,\pi]$ and hence is measurable on $[0,\pi]$ by adding whatever value to the function at $x=0$. The difference is just at one point, so it is almost everywhere, and we know a.e. does not matter in the integration and measurability.

Comment: Yes, we can use DCT here. But $\sin(nx)/(nx)\to0$ as $n\to\\infty$, not $1$.

Comment: Some would say that when you post an answer that's simply wrong you should fix it...

Comment: I didn't say that $\sin(nx)/(nx)\rightarrow 1$. I just wrote that $|\sin(nx)/nx|\leq 1$. We need a dominated integrable function on $[0,\pi]$, in this case I use $1$, why this is wrong?

Comment: Sorry - it looked like you were saying that the limit of the integral was $\int_0^\pi 1$.